# Azure Endpoints Protocol Differencess

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

Hello I was wondering during the development, what are the differences between the types of protocols that I can use for my endpoint?  the latest SDK had, HTTP, HTTPS, UDP and TCP.  I certainly understand what the differences between the http and Https, I also understand the differences between the TCP and UDP.

what I don't understand what are the differences between TCP and HTTP from the development perspective?

Comment: Are you configuring this in your cloud config files or web.config? In general clearly TCP and UDP are different beasts and need to be configured properly as endpoints.

Comment: I agree with you that the TCP and UDP are totally different however it is clearly when do I have to choose among those my question is how to choose between them and the HTTP & HTTPS protocols, what I know is that the HTTP and the HTTPS are based on the TCP so what are the differences? and when to use any of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP / UDP are lower level protocols in the OSI model than HTTP/ HTTPS. Actually HTTPS is combining two thing, HTTP over SSL.

Have a read through the Wikipedia article describing the [Osi Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model#Layer_5:_session_layer)

HTTP is a layer 7 (Application) protocol and as such has a strict set of rules governing how the messages are constructed and what are considered valid responses. It is not concerned with how the actual connection takes place or how the messages are routed.

TCP and UDP are layer 5 which means they are concerned with addressing, establishing connection, packetization and sequencing. Things that are needed to exchange a series of bytes (payloads) between two endpoints.

Usually when developing software you want to implement open and established protocols that simplify the task of integrating with systems from other vendors or opening up end points for others to consume. In this scenario, HTTP or HTTPS make sense.

If your system is a closed one where you control both the client and server applications or where performance is of paramount importance then TCP might be a good choice. Operating at this level means you have to concern yourself with issues of defining your own payload structure, security, packet loss etc.